# How can I pass mixin arguments along literally in LESS CSS?

Tags: css, less

This is my mixin:

```
.gradient (...) {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(@arguments);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(@arguments);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(@arguments);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(@arguments);
    background-image: linear-gradient(@arguments);
}
```

And I'm trying to use it like this:

```
.gradient(top, #333333 0%, #282828 100%);
```

The problem is that LESS is stripping away all the commas, so the output looks like this:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(top #333333 0% #272727 100%);
```

Is it possible to get LESS to pass along the arguments literally? Alternatively, how should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achive what you are looking for I think you have to pass the `@arguments` as a literal string using one of these syntax:

> 1. `~"top, #333333 0%, #282828 100%"`
> 2. `e("top, #333333 0%, #282828 100%")`

Syntax `~"value"` and `e("value")` are almost equivalent.

Then you should call your `.gradient( @arguments )` mixin like this:

> `.gradient( e("top, #333333 0%, #282828 100%") );`

Comment: This is helpful, but does anyone know how to break these literal strings among multiple lines for readability? It generates a parse error when I try.

Comment: Hi @michael, you can break the literal in smaller chunks and write them on multiple lines. if you have something like `filter: ~"alpha(opacity=@{opacity})";` you can write it like this: `filter: ~"alpha" ~"(" ~"opacity" ~"=" ~"@{opacity}" ~")";`